# How to create custom node edit form

Tags: 8, routes

```
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if($route = $collection->get('entity.node.edit_form')) {
      $route->setDefault('_entity_form', '\Drupal\alerts\Form\EditAdvisoryForm');
    }
  }
```

Causes a permission error. The logs say

> Path: /node/1277957/edit?destination=/admin/content.
> Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: in
> Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 117 of
> /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php).

It doesn't seem to prefill the form with the editable info. This is also not content type specific.

Please advise. Other posts close to this do not have an answer.

Comment: You need to define the custom edit form class as form handler in the entity type. Then you can use the form handler in `_entity_form`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283113/how-to-inject-entity-object-in-entityform. You can also replace the existing form handler in the entity type if you want to change the node edit form for the entire site without altering routes.

Comment: The link you provided doesnt even look related to my question. There is no route file as this is customizing a system edit form.

Comment: This doesn't matter. I add an answer to clarify the issue in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`_entity_form` doesn't accept a form class directly, only via a form handler. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes

> _entity_form: It is similar to _form, but it will provide an edit form for an entity. Entity form handlers are defined in the entity metadata
> (annotation). For example, _entity_form: node.default will display the
> default node form. "node" in node.default refers to the entity ID, and
> "default" refers to the form handler key.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can give an example with details. When I attempt the hook with key string as my content type, I get error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setFormClass() on null" i.e. that key isnt recognized

Comment: You have to use as key the entity type `node`. You can check the content type then in the form class.

Comment: Apparently not giving answers is close worthy

Comment: I don't get bonus points for answering your comment about the linked hook_entity_type_build() you first said was not related?

Comment: I stand corrected. You definitely do, though the same error received

Comment: When you manage that `_entity_form` injects the entity object the access error should go away and the form should be prefilled with the entity object's field values.

Comment: It appears the permission error was related to a 3rd party module. The edit form now displays; however, it is not prefilled. I have tried both with a router yml and routesubscriber. I also put NodeForm as my parent form, still the form is empty

Comment: For the last issue, I believe i missed calling the parent methods, obtaining the entity and prefill-ing the form programmatically. I initially added the form mode through the admin. One reference said this was required. Though a rocky road, you def sent me on the right path. Thanks! This may be a more in depth doc https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/creating-a-content-entity-type-in-drupal-8