# How to expand NodeForm so new argument can passed to it

Tags: nodes, forms, 9

I have a content type called service request, which have some conditional fields that each might appear or disappear based on an other field value called service type.

I have used conditional field and they work just right but for better user experience I want node form to be called using one of the service types.

so I tried to follow [this instructions provided by Jaypan to extend NodeForm](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-05-22/passing-a-parameter-to-a-nodeadd-form), but when overriding form function of NodeForm, it leads to `Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getBaseFormId()`

this is how I used to create $form:

```
class ServiceBuilderForm extends NodeForm {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $serviceType = NULL) {
    // Added as a fallback in case a developer uses this form without passing
    // $someId:
    if (is_null($serviceType)) {
      $form = [
        '#prefix' => '<p class="error">',
        '#suffix' => '</p>',
        '#markup' => $this->t('Form is missing Service Type which is required'),
      ];
    }
    else {
      $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
      // Do something with $form and $some_id
    }

    return $form;
  }
}
```

and in my Controller I have get my form using:

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\{my_module}\Form\ServiceFormBuilder', $serviceType);
```

Comment: You need a form mode https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230527/how-do-i-load-a-form-with-a-specific-form-display-form-mode and you don't necessarily need a controller https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244898/how-to-utilize-custom-form-modes-to-edit-a-user-entity

Comment: In `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\{my_module}\Form\ServiceFormBuilder', $serviceType);` the class name is not the same used when defining the form class, which is `ServiceBuilderForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have integrated the form class in the entity type as form mode

```
function mymodule_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->setFormClass('service', 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\ServiceBuilderForm');
}
```

and invoked the node form in a controller

```
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($node, 'service');
```

or without controller directly in a route:

```
_entity_form: 'node.service'
```

the entity including the field data is passed to your form

```
class ServiceBuilderForm extends NodeForm {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $node = $this->entity;
    if ($node->getType() == 'service_request') {
      $field_value = $node->field_service_type->value;
```

and you avoid the error from your question that the entity is null.

Comment: thanks for your wonderful answer

Answer (score 1):

While 4k4 provided a great answer on how to extend an Entity Form and how to instantiate that , for any one who just needs to extend NodeForm class to send new argument to that, they can use a simple code like below :

```
$node = $this->entityService
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create(['type' => 'service']);

$form = $this->entityService
  ->getFormObject('node', 'default')
  ->setEntity($node);

$form = $this->myFormBuilder->getForm($form, $questions);//arguments will be passed in form and can be accessed in form using `$form_state->getBuildInfo()['args'][0]`

$form['field_service_type']['widget']['#default_value'] = $rbid;
$form['field_service_type']['widget']['#value'] = $rbid;
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_form_validate';

return [
  'form' => $form,
];
```

in the code above `$this->entityService` is an EntityTypeManager object injected to my controller, when I got the usual form object I have set service type field (not recommended cause it is related to widget type).

> as mentioned in code as comment arguments passed can be accessed in
> form using `$form_state->getBuildInfo()['args']`

So just in mind that if you need to pass arguments to an EntityForm and you are looking for a simple solution, then this code might help.

Comment: BTW [EntityFormBuilderInterface::getForm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityFormBuilderInterface%3A%3AgetForm/9.1.x) also accepts arguments as third parameter $form_state_additions. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219431/entity-form-additional-arguments